# ngrx issues with concatLatestFrom and skipwhile

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have to call two endpoints and for the second I need to wait for a value from the first. since the first value will be in the store anyways.

I am following this pattern:

```
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType('SOME_ACTION'),
  withLatestFrom(store.select(someThing).skipWhile(c=>c==null)),
  switchMap(([action, state]) => hitEndPoint(state.data))
)
```

The problem is that the withLatestFrom runs once and completes the stream (I think), and that is not making the action trigger. What I actually want is to wait the state to not be null and then run the hitEndPoint function.

I looked around did not find a example that actually worked. Filter also ended not working. Any ideas how to get this behavior

Comment: Is the first endpoint always called immediately before the second one?

Comment: They are dependent dropdown values. API1 retrieves the data  for the API2 and then API3. meaning 2 and 3 depends on 1 and 3 depends on 1 and 2.

Comment: How does the user get into the situation you describe in the question? ie: assuming first drop down is populated when page loads, user selects a value then second drop down is populated accordingly. User then chooses a value in the second drop down, you now have values for 1 and 2 (they are not null) to make the 3rd call . Where does the null value come into it?

Comment: It is the initial state, for all values. But the way I ended solving this was to keep the local state in a store as well. and then having an action for that. onValue1Change, the API2 effect listen to the value1 change and since I know there is now a value there I don't need any filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `filter` operator.

```
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType('SOME_ACTION'),
  withLatestFrom(store.select(someThing).filter(c=>c!==null)),
  switchMap(([action, state]) => hitEndPoint(state.data))
)
```

Comment: This works, but fundamentally I was doing the logic wrong. either skipWhile or filter will work. But the effect won't be triggered anyways. Instead I need to listen also to the change event as an stream so when the data is then not null the effect would run.

For example, a collection of inputs you would need also to listen to the changes of those instead of dispatching a single event (which will not trigger) but if all events are catched as soon as all is not null it will work.